# GetDIBits unexpected output

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to capture a portion of my screen but the code outputs 0s where there shouldn't be any

code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

    int x = 745; int y = 345;
    int w = 250; int h = 480;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
    HDC hCaptureDC  = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w+x, h+y);

    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hCaptureDC,x,y,w,h, hdc,x,y,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT); 
    
    BITMAPINFO BmpInfo = {0};
    BmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BmpInfo.bmiHeader);
    BmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    // Get the BITMAPINFO structure from the bitmap
    GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, h, NULL, &BmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[BmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
    // get the actual bitmap buffer
    GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, h, (LPVOID)lpPixels, &BmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    vector<vector<int>> vect;
    vector<int> tmp;
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<w*h*4;i+=4){
        //only record B value
        tmp.push_back((int)lpPixels[i]);
        if(j==w){vect.push_back(tmp);tmp={};j=0;}
        j++;
    }
    ofstream out;
    out.open("out0.txt");
    for(int i=vect.size()-1;i!=0;i--){
        for(int l=vect[i].size()-1;l>=0;l--){out << vect[i][l];out << " ";}
        out << endl;
    }
    out.close();

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    delete[] lpPixels;
    cout << "took a screenshot\n";
```

expected output:

```
23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 
23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 
etc
```

actual output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 0 0 0 0 0 
etc
```

compiler: mingw32-g++ (gdi32 linked)

The output should be the blue value of each pixel (stored in BGRA format) and every pixel in the capture was blue, so there shouldn't have been any 0s.
So what's going wrong here?

Comment: Checking return value of function calls is a good idea, this way you wouldn't have to guess what's wrong. Try to step the code with debugger to see where it fails. It could be `GetDIBits`, because the passed `BITMAPINFO` is too small (can happen if bitdepth is less than 32), could get `GetDC`, something related to restrictions, or whatever.

Comment: P.S. And speaking performance-wise, it's better to create DIB (see `CreateDIBSection`). Because in your example you first allocate the birmap of the needed size, and then in addition you allocate an array to store its bits.